# Why pass the RowMetadata argument as an additional parameter?

Tags: r2dbc

I am writing an R2DBC implementation for YDB.

Interface Result has a map method where two parameters are expected BiFunction(Row, RowMetadata), but why pass RowMetadata here if there is a getMetadata() method for the Row interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bit of history attached. R2DBC SPI started with `Result.map(BiFunction<Row, RowMetadata>)` in its very first release to decouple `Row` from its metadata.

As the specification evolved, we eventually added further methods and evolved the readable targets to Stored Procedures, which are `OutParameters` with their own metadata type. Both `OutParameters` and `Row` now are subtypes of `Readable` and the preferred way to consume results is by using `Result.map(Function<Readable>)`.

After adding metadata to `Row` and `OutParameters`, we didn't want to break existing client implementations because the value of breaking clients (by removing the method accepting `BiFunction`) would not outweigh by any means the benefit.

You could well argue that there is a bit of redundancy and you're right. `map(BiFunction)` represents `Result.filter(instanceof Row).flatMap(it -> Mono.just(mapper.apply(row, row.getMetadata()`) and `Result.map(Function)` equals to `Result.filter(instanceof Readable).flatMap(it -> mapper.apply(it)`. However, we found for the different styles of consuming `Result`s, that these methods make quite some sense.